# css transitions ignored because react rerenders

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to use css transitions, but as react re-renders a component, they are getting ignored. Let's imagine the use case, in which my `render()` function outputs something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li className={this.state.path==="/menu1/" ? "active" : "inactive"}>
    menu 1
  </li>
  <li className={this.state.path==="/menu2/" ? "active" : "inactive"}>
    menu 2
  </li>
  <li className={this.state.path==="/menu3/" ? "active" : "inactive"}>
    menu 3
  </li>
</ul>
```

Let's imagine that:

- .active is putting a blue background and animating on background color
- .inactive is putting a red background and animating on background color

The app loads with /menu1 being active. Using react router I update the state and the component should update. When navigating to a new route (eg "/menu2/") everything works, but as a re-rendering occurs, my transition gets ignored.

The only solution I saw was to modify the DOM using componentDidUpdate, but I don't want react to manipulate the DOM directly, so my question is :

How can I animate elements properly using react together with css?

Comment: One thing that worked for me is using modifiers. So have a class with the transition that is being always applied, and apply a modifier class if active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way would be to use css modifiers for applying different styles.

This means that your code should look something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li className={`nav-item ${this.state.path==="/menu1/" ? "nav-item--active" : ""}`}>
    menu 1
  </li>
  <li className={`nav-item ${this.state.path==="/menu2/" ? "nav-item--active" : ""}`}>
    menu 2
  </li>
  <li className={`nav-item ${this.state.path==="/menu3/" ? "nav-item--active" : ""}`}>
    menu 3
  </li>
</ul>
```

Let's say you want a background transition. You would apply the transition styles and the initial background colour to the `.nav-item` class. And after that you will add a rule for `.nav-item--active` that just changes the background colour. I think by doing this you will get the expected result.

Comment: I don't understand this answer, you're doing the exact same thing OP was doing, and completely ignoring the component re-render that is the root of his problem.

How exactly is using BEM style supposed to help with a component re-rendering problem he is having?

Comment: I'm also confused here.  this "modifiers" thing is just made up right?  i.e the browser or CSS spec doesn't know anything about this, it's just a naming convention (BEM).  Does this have different behavior than the original post?  And why?

Comment: So just to be clear... modifiers are not a must in order to make this work. They are just a nice thing to know about and structure code. The key here was not to toggle between two classes but instead have one applied always, and the other one applied conditionally.
And yes, modifiers are just a convention and not something that the browser interprets differently.

Comment: Also for @TtotheJ ...my example is slightly different. And the root of the problem is indeed the re-rendering and how react does the DOM diff-ing.